# Complete stable minimal hypersurface in positively curved manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

Let $(M^n,g)$ be a complete noncompact orientable Riemannian manifold with positive sectional curvature. Can we find an orientable stable minimal hypersurface $N$ in $M$?

It follows from [R. Schoen's work](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Estimates-for-stable-minimal-surfaces-in-three-Schoen/f65ada187de5e3a149438abf4fd08cab7c57ff1f) that if $n=3$, no such hypersurface $N$ exists. Moreover, if $N$ is compact, this is also impossible by the stability inequality. Are there any result for the general case?

Comment: This seems like a difficult problem. I suspect it might be open, because the following question is: `If $\Sigma^3 \subset \mathbf{R}^4$ is a complete stable minimal surface with trivial normal bundle, is $\Sigma$ a plane?' It is a conjecture of Schoen that this is true; it's recorded as Conjecture 2.12 in the book of Colding--Minicozzi for example. One of the difficulties is that estimates for the area growth are hard to come by when $n \geq 4$ (when these are available you can use the work of Schoen--Simon--Yau), another that the logarithmic cut-off estimate is not available anymore.

Comment: Be careful also to distinguish between 'orientable' and 'trivial normal bundle'. They are not the same; surfaces with the latter property are also called *two-sided*. The way it's stated I think your claim is not quite correct: $\mathbf{R} P^{2n-1} \subset \mathbf{R} P^{2n}$ is an orientable, stable minimal hypersurface.

Comment: @LeoMoos Here the ambient manifold is assumed to be orientable. So the "two-sided" condition is equivalent to the orientable hypersurface.

Comment: My bad, you're right, I missed that part of your question!

Comment: A small comment. The assumption that $M^n$ is orientable is superfluous. A complete noncompact positively curved manifold $M^n$ must be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ because its soul is a point.

Answer (score 3):

You can construct a positively curved $(M^n,g)$ for any $n\geq 4$ that admits a stable minimal hypersurface. This is described in Example 1.2 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.07708.pdf). (That paper also contains some non-existence results for $n=4$ under additional curvature assumptions.)